# How can I do a if then statement in javascript between websites?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a website that depends on another website.
If this other website has a certain word written on the index page at the time, then the text on my website says Yes, if it doesn't have that word, then the font on my website says No.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have control over the other site? Does it allow cross origin requests? If not then `Javascript` is not the way to go about this.

Comment: no, i don't have control over it.

Comment: If not javascript, then what would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: I should correct myself. Server-side Javascript such as `node.js` would be okay for this. It is only client-side `Javascript` that is not suitable (for security reasons, browsers do not allow cross domain requests). You might find more resources for how to do it in PHP though. Basically just make an `HTTP GET` request for the page you want to load, then parse the HTML of that page to determine what you want about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to do that through a server side code, which can do cross-domain GET requests for the target websites, check for your desired word and then display the result on your website. You can use php, aspx.net and many more.

Comment: How would I create a server side code through php?